# Can I get three-way *word* diffs using e.g. dwdiff with diff3?

Tags: shell, diff, three-way-merge

I know there are [GUI's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572237/whats-the-best-three-way-merge-tool) that show word-diffs in three-way diff, and there are command line tools that show two-way word-highlighting diffs.

But is there a command-line way I can show **three-way** diffs with **word-higlighting** the same way that I can get two-way diffs word-higlighted with `diff -u a b | dwdiff -u` ?

Answer (score 0):

[`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) (which you can use outside a Git repository with `--no-index`, but that would be a two-way diff) does have word diff ([`--word-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diffltmodegt), with [regex if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54072200/6309), using [`--word-diff-regex`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---word-diff-regexltregexgt)).

See also [color-words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36437292/6309):

[image: color words]

That would be a command-line way to get a word diff.

Comment: `dwdiff` already does this without even needing git. The question is about **three-way** word diffs

Comment: @unhammer three-way (that I present here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/6309) means a version history in order to get a common ancestor. Hence Git. I don't know of command-line tool which would take three arguments (remote, local, base) *and* does word-diff highlighting.